# Wordpress: Using wp_insert_post() to fill custom post type fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, content-management-system

I have created a custom post type `wrestling` and created its corresponding custom fields using Advanced Custom Fields. Now, I wanted the users to fill this custom form on the front end, so that on submission, the data would get automatically updated in the custom post type in the dashboard. For this purpose, I created a custom page and assigned a custom template to it which contained the required form. There are four HTML form fields that the users are supposed to fill, named `name`, `venue`, `main_event` and `fee` respectively.

The custom form fields that I created using Advanced Custom Fields are named as `promotion_name`, `venue`, `main_event_` and `price` respectively. Now, in order to fill the data entered by the users on the front end onto the custom post type fields at the dashboard, I tried using the `wp_insert_post()` function as follows:

```
$post_information = array(
        'promotion_name' => $_POST['name'],
        'venue' => $_POST['venue'],
        'main_event_' => $_POST['main_event'],
        'price' => $_POST['fee'],
        'post_type' => 'wrestling',
    );

    wp_insert_post( $post_information );
```

However, after the user submits the form, a new entry (no_title) does appear in my custom post type, but the custom form fields are still empty (See images below:)

[image]

[image]

I'm sure this is because I'm not using the `wp_insert_post()` correctly for updating custom post types. I'd really appreciate some help here. Thanks.

PS: This is how I have defined my custom post type in `functions.php`:

```
<?php 
function wrestling_show_type()
{
    register_post_type('wrestling',
                    array('labels' => array('name' => 'Wrestling Shows', 'singular_name' => 'Wrestling Show'),
                        'public' => true,
                        'has_archive' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'wrestling')));

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'wrestling_show_type');
?>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have used ACF, you should use their API to interact with the fields. There's a method called [`update_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) that does exactly what you are looking for. This method takes 3 parameters:

```
update_field($field_key, $value, $post_id)
```

`$field_key` is an ID ACF gives to each field you create. This image, taken from their very own documentation, shows you how to get it:

[image: How to get the field key]

**Edit:** `$field_key` Will also accept the field name.

`$value` and `$post_id` are pretty straight forward, they represent the value you want to set the field with, and the post you are updating.

In your case, you should do something to retrieve this `$post_id`. Fortunately, that's what `wp_insert_post()` returns. So, you can do something like this:

```
$post_information = array(
    //'promotion_name' => $_POST['name'],
    'post_type' => 'wrestling'
);

$postID = wp_insert_post( $post_information ); //here's the catch
```

With the ID, then things are easy, just call `update_field()` for each field you want to update.

```
update_field('whatever_field_key_for_venue_field', $_POST['venue'], $postID);
update_field('whatever_field_key_for_main_event_field', $_POST['main_event'], $postID);
update_field('whatever_field_key_for_fee_field', $_POST['fee'], $postID);
```

So basically what you're doing is creating the post first, and then updating it with the values.

I've done this kind of stuff in the `functions.php` file, and it worked fine. From what I've seen, I think you are using this routine in a template file of some sort. I think it's gonna work fine, you just gotta make sure the ACF plugin is activated.

**EDIT:**

I forgot the `promotion_name` field. I commented the line inside `$post_information`, as it's not going to work. You should use `update_field()` instead, just like the other 3.

```
update_field('whatever_field_key_for_promotion_name_field', $_POST['name'], $postID);
```

Comment: I managed to update my form fields using the `add_post_meta()` function, which I think is exactly similar to the `update_field()` function, right?

Comment: I think it ultimately does that, but I'd stick with the plugin API, as its more consistent to a field created by the plugin. If you have different kinds of fields, such as WYSIWYG editors, or maybe subfields, using `add_post_meta()` can become quite tricky, so why not let the plugin do the job for you?

Comment: Oh alright, I'll try to modify my code, this time using the `update_field()` method instead. Thanks.

Comment: yea lemme know if you find any trouble

Comment: Hi, but if you develop on localhost and then go publish to production, production will have different keys for the same fields ? So then 'update_field' would crash ?

Comment: Although this is pretty old and it may have changed since then, I think the keys would be the same. If not, you can update the database with whatever keys you want, or create production specific files to deal with the ID. Again, this answer is old and ACF probably has changed since them. I'd suggest some testing

Comment: And also, by the magic of reading what I wrote three years ago, I found out that `$field_key` also takes the *Field Name*, so you don't need to worry about keys change, since your names won't

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to add custom fields data directly when creating a post. It is mentioned in the [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) docs. Just pass an array with custom field keys and values to `meta_input` like this:

```php
wp_insert_post([
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type'   => 'wrestling',
  'meta_input'  => [
    'my_custom_field_1' => 'beep',
    'my_custom_field_2' => 'boop',
  ]
]);
```

I'm looking into this approach to avoid a dozen of update_field() database calls and make it less resource intensive, but I have yet to prove this approach actually makes less database calls in the background.

Comment: Does this approach work with ACF custom fields?

Comment: @Space Yes it does. ACF leverages the core custom fields system, so this meta_input is also compatible with ACF.

Comment: While the previous answer is technically correct, I feel that this answer shows a better way of doing it.